# How do I consistently shove and tackle people in Assassin's Creed on the PC?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood, assassins-creed-2

I just recently started playing Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood on the PC. When I started Sequence 2, there is a mission where I have to tackle a guy who stole my money. I keep chasing him, but I can't find a reliable way to tackle him.

The "Shift" key contextually changes from "Shove" to "Tackle" but I can never manage to consistently execute the tackle. In general, I leave it up to chance and somehow I get it to trigger. I also can't figure out how to shove people either. Usually I just end up falling into them and tripping.

I had this same problem in Assassin's Creed 2, but I managed to get through the whole game without really needing to perform either of these moves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ***Tackle*** someone you need to:

1. Be in **high profile** mode, by holding the right mouse button.
2. Be running, with your **legs**, by holding <kbd>Space</kbd> or the 4th mouse button (5-button config).
3. Tackle them with your **free arm**, by *tapping* <kbd>Shift</kbd> or the 5th mouse button (5-button config).

---

To ***Shove*** people you need to:

1. Be in **high profile** mode and running with your **legs**.
2. Be ready to shove with your **free arm**, by *holding* <kbd>Shift</kbd> or the 5th mouse button (5-button config).
3. Run in to them. As long as you're *holding* your **free arm** ready they will be shoved aside.

---

I also found it a little bit awkward to reliably tackle the correct target, but in general you should be close to and running towards the target when you tap the **free arm** button, and ideally not when near other people that might be targeted by mistake.

Comment: Is there a way to run without using your legs?

Comment: @Thrillho no, but they're highlighted in my answer because those are the way the game specifically refers to the basic controls (weapon hand, free hand, legs, head).

Comment: @Thrillho Get an ancient wheelchair?

Comment: Wow. I can't believe it never occurred to me that I didn't need to hold 'Space' for shoving or tackling. I can actually tackle consistently without sprinting.